# React Table + Searching ARRAY

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I need help with filtering data in React Table.
I am taking data from API and storing it in the state with react hooks. And I created a table using React Table lib.
So, pagination and other things work well, but I have an input section, where you enter a name after that table should be dynamically changed end find let say a user from the table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wrote the state this way:

```
import React from 'react';
const usersData = [{name:'x'},{name:'y'}];

const component = () =>{
 const [users,setUsers] = React.useState(usersData);
 // naïve filtration method
 const filterByInput=(input)=>{
  setUsers(usersData.filter((i)=>i.name===input)
 }
 return (...);
}
```

You can make it a lot better if you use [`fuse.js`](https://fusejs.io/)
Where the implementation of it would be like this

```
import React from 'react';
import fuse from 'fuse.js';
const usersData = [{name:'x'},{name:'y'}];

const component = () =>{
 const [users,setUsers] = React.useState(usersData);
 const filterByInput=(input)=>{
  const fuse = new Fuse(people, {
    keys: ['name', /*any other key that you want to search for*/]
  })
  setUsers(fuse.search(input).map(i=>i.item));
 }
 return (...);
}
```